# immediate consistency on projection with event sourcing and cqrs

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, consistency, eventual-consistency

When using a SQL journal in an event sourced system, is it ok to update the journal and one or more projections in the same transaction ? Is it an anti pattern ?

The pros I can think of is this the consistency of the view is immediate, but what are the cons ? Performance ?

Comment: can you add more details? WHY do you require that a projection be updated in the same transaction with the event? projections in general follow eventual consistency, so whats the use-case here?

Comment: We want to avoid eventual consistency because we don't want to have specific frontend code to handle it

Answer (score 1):

Scalability is the biggest price.

But interestingly you say it's 'immediate' but that isn't strictly true.

There is still a delay while the transaction completes and depending on how long that takes or how many transactions per second are being made, you run the risk of unnecessary concurrency conflicts.

You still have to pay the "eventual consistency" price, you just pay it in a blocking way (nothing wrong with that if it's a conscious choice).

Hope that helps.